# Is there anyway to stop android studio ask every time i undo reformat code?

Tags: android-studio, ide

As title,  I'm using Android Studio to create app, every time do reformatting code then press undo short key, this IDE show up [announcement like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2g00.png)

This is really annoying, especially with the person who press reformat short key all the time like me

Anroid Studio version: 3.1.2
OS: Windows 10 build 17134

Comment: Please mention Operating system as well as a version of Android Studio,
by which I suggest you.

Comment: I'm using Anroid Studio 3.1.2 on Windows
thank for ur suggestion

Comment: You can go to Preferences->Code Style->General->Formatter Control and check Enable formatter markers in comments for this to work.

Comment: ur way is not work, it just turn of the formater